# "ещё и с ней" vs "ещё с ней"

Tags: выбор-слова

> You'll have to babysit her, **too**. {= her as well as him}

In conversation, I wanted to express this idea in an sarcastic tone:

> Тебе **ещё и с ней** нянчиться придётся.
>
> {or}: Тебе **ещё с ней** нянчиться придётся.

I'm torn between the two. I wonder if the addition of "и" is required here and the latter sounds odd?

Answer (score 3):

**Ещё** on its own means 'more', not 'too':

- Тебе с ней **ещё** нянчиться придется. - You'll have to do **more** babysitting with her.

Your variant:

- Тебе **ещё** с ней нянчиться придётся.

is pretty much equivalent to the above.

**Еще и** means 'too' but be careful with emphasis and placement:

**Еще и с ней** puts emphasis on **ней** (her) which implies that you were babysitting someone else and now you will have to babysit **her**, too.

**Ещё и нянчиться** emphasises **нянчиться** which is probably what you wanted:

- Тебе **ещё и** нянчиться с ней придется. - You'll have to babysit her, too.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax depends on what you're trying to convey

> Тебе ещё и с ней нянчиться придётся

as explained by Sergey Slepov

> Тебе ещё { } с ней нянчиться придётся

I would read as emphasizing **нянчиться**, i.e. *on top of all the troubles you'll have to do also babysitting*.

Technically it can be construed as emphasizing **ещё** to mean *doing some more babysitting to what has already been done*. But if this is indeed the idea, to lessen ambiguity i would place **ещё** at the end

> Тебе { } с ней нянчиться придётся ещё

This is still not ideal but i think a little clearer and context may help.

In spoken language the syntax is less demanding because import can be emphasized with intonation.

Adding **и** before the word needing emphasis seems to resolve this ambiguity, **ещё** isn't one of them however.

Comment: Hi. I've got used to the astonishing flexibility of the word orders in Russian, but where in a sentence does the emphasis in terms of meaning generally fall on? Is it the last word in a sentence?

Comment: @Alone-zee hi, i guess so, but this would not suffice, to sound idiomatic the rest of the sentence will have to be rearranged as well, for example, original sentence ***В прошлом году он подарил мне дорогой подарок***, now let's emphasize different parts by moving them to the end of the sentence A) ***Дорогой подарок он подарил мне `в прошлом году`***; B) ***Дорогой подарок в прошлом году подарил мне `он`***; С) ***Дорогой подарок в прошлом году он подарил `мне`***; D) ***Подарок в прошлом году он мне подарил/он подарил мне/подарил он мне `дорогой`***

Comment: E) В прошлом году дорогой подарок он подарил мне. Like, he has a habit of making expensive gifts to somebody annually, so that was not a big deal/surprise, but that he changed addressee, that in prior years he gifted someone else and now switched to gifting me, that should be noted. And C) might actually be making light stress on the first part. Like some ancient folklore tails intonations. Like "дорогой ЖЕ подарок в прошлом году он подарил мне". Yeah, the emphasis is somewhat swinging between start and end of sentences, depending on the context. Our eagle has two heads afterall. Complicated

Comment: There is a great American sci-fi novel "Enemy mine" and it was amazingly translated to Russian. The closing chapters of it touch a required ancient ritual (plus an ancient sacred book) that a human prepares himself to commit later as a substitute for the dying alien. So, that "old epos speak" touch of "First term matters" is used in those parts. At one point it gets directly contrasted with "modern casual speak" way of expressing the same idea. And, the novel itself is brilliant anyway :-D

Answer (score 0):

> Тебе ещё с ней нянчиться придётся.

This is more neutral tone, as if the sayer were reminding the listener. "You will have to babysit her as well, don't forget, so you will have little spare time!"

> Тебе ещё и с ней нянчиться придётся.

This sounds like the sayer were discouraging the listener from something.

Answer (score 0):

I would extend upon Sergey's answer too.

> Тебе с ней **ещё** нянчиться придется. - You'll have to do **more** babysitting with her.

I disagree here. I would say that phrase conveys "start" rather than "more": "You'll have to **start** babysit her". The "more" motive might be implied here of course. Like, if you are babysiting 10 persons, adding 11th to the list is making more of the babysitting. Or, if you focus on time/effort spent, then starting babysitting makes you spend yet more time.

But those ideas are different.

> You'll have to do **more** babysitting with her.

implies that

- you already babysit
- you babysit not enough, if you was babysitting for example for an hour a day, now you would babysit for three hours a day

Those implications are missing in "Тебе с ней ещё [потом] нянчиться придется".
What actually implied here is surprise, unexpected consequences.

You do not expect that your current decision would later add babysitting her to your current list of burdens, but it will. Think again if you want to make your burdens yet heavier than they already are. There would be a price to pay that you overlook and do not expect yet.

That is what conveyed here. "To all your chores, you would later have to babysit her as well", like this.

This notion of unexpected consequences, of a probably unpleasant surprise incoming is what conveyed by "ещё" here.

> Еще и с ней puts emphasis on ней (her) which implies that you were babysitting someone else and now you will have to babysit her, too.

Absolutely correct.

> Ещё и нянчиться emphasises нянчиться

...and emphasizes it in the way, that you already has some list of activities you do with her, and now that list would get extended with babysitting.

Like, you were providing for her with money, food, medicine, and it is getting snowballing to the point it can now be called babysitting.

Or like you intend to do some limited activity, like going to parties together, but that person is known to call her acquaintances in the dead night and whine about her troubles, real or imagined. So, you get a forewarning, that you would have to BOTH walk her to the parties AND (unexpectedly) to wipe her night tears way too often.

Personally I derive it from how lists are described in Russian (not only in Russian, of course). Красный, желтый, синий **И** зелёный. Red, yellow, blue **AND** green.

In such phrases like these yours the inserted "И" implies some already existing list that would be yet extended. And the positioning of this "И" specifies which one of the few concurrent lists would get extended. Was it the list of activities with a certain persons, or the list of persons you engage in certain activity with or some other list.

So, the specific idea you want to convey is "her as well as him" - extending the list of persons for the specific activity. That positions "И" in front of "HER", thus "Тебе ещё **и с ней** нянчиться придётся".

Note, it can be worded without "ещё" - like "Тогда тебе и с ней придётся нянчиться". This would imply "It would not be that much of a surprise, and you probably already know it, but still you better consider it once again, for personally I would had not chosen this path".